# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, top-7, site-attributes

One of the big 7 questions.

Answer (score 2):

To start generic:
- A list of questions that are allowed and what not.
- Some guidelines on how to ask and answer a question.
- Of course the standard SO mechanics.
- Names and task of the moderators.

Answer (score 2):

@Gamecat has some good suggestions. I'd add (I'll update this if i think of more):

- When a question should be in meta.
- When a question should be in gaming.stackexchange.com.
- Profanity policy, [if any](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/how-to-ask-about-games-with-impolite-names).