# How to ask about games with "impolite" names?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-topic

Several common card games have "impolite" names.

- Bull $...
- Egyptian Rat $....
- <strike>Pimp the Backhanding</strike>

How do we want to address this on the site?  Should we not list the full name of the game as I have here?

Comment: I completely miss the point. I can't even remotely understand the kind of people who gets "offended" by things like that.

Comment: I think this is one of those points where the actual owners of *.stackexchange have come down with a "no impolite words" policy, so discussion is academic at this point.

Answer (score 11):

<sub>(I continued to bowdlerize in this post until we decide, even though I'm arguing that it's silly)</sub>

SO had this [argument](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive) with [Brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), and I generally think they came out on the wrong side -- it's patently not offensive if it's part of the name, and people should be able to deal with it in that case. There's a difference between:

> What are the rules to the card game Bullsh*t?

and:

> You are a f*cking idiot if you use that strategy

The only good arguments I've ever heard for censoring are:

- The people that do care care a *lot*, and it's easier to just avoid the edit war and cave
- Some people are accessing the site from behind a proxy that will block sites with cursing

So, I think it's a personal problem that people should deal with on their own (get a userscript that censors websites if you want, rather than trying to get the whole Internet to censor itself), but unlike on the [English.SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive) we can function without them if we really have enough users that can't handle it

Comment: I think the big argument is the proxy.  I don't want to limit availability.

Comment: There really aren't that many proxies that block on the mere presence of a word - some might black out the word.  Much more likely is that a site that is, after all, about games will get noticed for having rude words in, then get added to a "gaming" category, that a lot of filters block because it mostly consists of on-line flash games that eat bandwidth and users' time.

Comment: So if a game had the N word in it, you'd be ok with that.

Comment: @Lance I don't think that game would sell very well, but I'd be ok with calling it by its name, yes. I don't think that's a case we're really going to need to deal with though

Comment: The most likely source of those types of proxies / blacklists are (I think) corporate sites and kiddie blocking software.  People shouldn't probably be visiting this site on company time anyways, and I expect eventually there will be more mature content on this site and explicit game titles are just one part of that.  In either case, having this site blocked for those users is an appropriate response.

Comment: I just read the SO question you linked to. **Really** interesting read. wow. Just with all the give and take going on there, every beta user on this site should probably read it. I do think some of the arguments there are not as applicable here - SO is a source for programmers, who are arguably at work.  This is a recreational site, so one of the best pro-censorship arguments (by Pollyanna: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive/24153#24153) doesn't hold much sway with me.

Comment: @DaveParillo for those of us with *interesting* work schedules there's a difference between company time and company hardware.

Answer (score 10):

If the *name* is obscene it should be allowed, how else could it be searched for after all.

However, **offensive** or **obscene** language used out of context, or to attack of abuse somone should be deleted - this is pretty obvious i think, as the answer would probably already be voted down / not useful.

Comment: I think this boils it down rather nicely! If Wikipedia can do it then so should we.

Answer (score 2):

My main vote for no is a fairly basic one: how to you ask a question about what might be a fairly obscure game without referring to it by name?  Do you call it the '[Game That Must Not Be Named](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/21232/adlung-spiele-edition)' and link to an external site with the moxie to call a spade a spade?

Answer (score 1):

I went right to the source and asked the horse: BGG does not appear to censor game titles. Go there and search 'p*mp' or 'sh*t'.

If the geek can live with being inaccessible behind some proxies, so can we.

Comment: So if BGG jumped off a cliff, we should too? :) We can't risk having the entire *.stackexchange.com domain put on corporate blacklists because a few people want to talk about profane board game titles. Ain't worth it.

Comment: @Jeff Do you have evidence of proxies that blacklist sites based on occasional curse words on sibling subdomains? Censoring four-letter words will be a lot of manual work, and make it harder to discuss certain games, whose names are said four letter words, without any demonstrable benefit. You can't exactly censor curse words on http://english.stackexchange.com, so they will already be appearing on other subdomains. In fact, many show up on StackOverflow: http://goo.gl/At5E (Google search for various inappropriate words on StackOverflow); is StackOverflow already blocked by said proxies?

Comment: @Jeff - Well, I suppose you can drag out other parental chestnuts, so I'll beat you to it: Your roof, your rules. :) But BGG has chosen some excellent cliffs to jump off of when it comes to running a boardgame community site, you must admit. And **I** must admit, I wasn't thinking about *.SE.com, I was thinking about boardgames. What forest? All I see are these trees....

Comment: I actually agree that censoring is unnecessary, but I don't agree with your rationale. -1 if I had the rep.

Comment: @JeffAtwood So even wikipedia is using words as they are. Does that mean they are blacklisted?

Answer (score -3):

### Don't.

Comment: Could you expand on that answer a little?  Or perhaps a lot...

Comment: Don't...ask about them at all?